# Seaside Smalltalk Removes Comments on Accept

Tags: comments, format, settings, smalltalk, seaside

I've searched all the internet to find an answer, and I really have no idea how to fix this:

When I ctrl-s (Accept) sth in System Browser, all my comments are removed and the code is automatically formatted in the way I wouldn't like it to be. What is worse "Auto format on Accept" in settings is turned off. I am using Seaside 3.0.7, and I really think it's annoying - I don't have this problem in "clear" Pharo.

So I will be really happy, if someone could tell me the answer to my problem = how to disable this auto format & comment removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your *.changes* file is broken or not accessible.

Comment: What should I do with this, exactly?

Comment: Ok. I redownloaded Seaside one-click, and copied only the .changes file to the folder with Pier3.image [changed name to Pier3.changes]. Everything is fine now. Thanks.

Comment: So it's the `Decompiler` kicking in. Interesting that the OP didn't mention `Decompiler`'s other symptom, losing variable names and using `t1`, `t2`, ... instead.